# Can I get the Wordpress Divi Editor Search Module to search text

Tags: wordpress, divi

I am developing a webpage which has to host 100s of videos (link to youtube vidoes) and I need a way to search these, but the Divi Search Module only seems to search posts or pages. Can I build my own search module or get this one to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can create your own search module by creating shortcode and put it in DIVI, or you can use any plugin to search for custom type, or you can use this article to make default search to search custom post type

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89886/how-to-create-a-custom-search-for-custom-post-type